# Changes to minio browser do not appear when running minio server

Tags: javascript, node.js, go, minio

My goal is to modify the `Minio` browser for front end appearance in house. I'd like to add features too but can't seem to get either to work and feel like I'm missing something about how go accesses npm or the browser.

I have made changes to the `Minio web browser (javascript)` and can see them when running with `npm` `(in ./browser 'npm run release;npm run dev')`, but when I try to run minio server built with the same git clone (changes is browser subdir) and browse to `localhost:9000` I don't see any of the changes.

It would also be nice to run the browser with `npm` and connect to the running server `"./minio server ~/data"`, but they don't seem to talk and I'm unclear on how they're connected.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a simple case of all the things I tried and in the right order.

Correct order:

```
cd browser; npm run release
cd ..; make
./minio server ~/minio-data
```

It seems I'd tried all of these separately but not in the obvious order. I'm assuming npm makes the `ui-assets.go` which gets included by the `make`